# How to get default component through jira-python

Tags: python, jira, python-jira

I have been trying to programatically retrieve the default component set for a JIRA project with little success.

Currently, I have tried

```
jira.createmeta('PROJ_NAME')
```

and

```
jira.project('PROJ_NAME')
```

Trying to understand the API output is troubling. I believe it might not be possible but I atleast want to confirm this before making this final assumption.

Is there an easy way to retrieve what component was set as the default in the jira-python api?

For reference:

https://jira-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know - and I am pretty sure about that, it is not possible to define a default component for a project.
Maybe there are workarounds with post transition functions but this is not an out-of-the-box feature.

Hence it`s not possible to get this information through any API!